# Population Dynamics model

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

I am currently searching for population dynamics models. 
Concerning animal population growth, I have found the following so far  :

- [Growth models for fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_dynamics_of_fisheries#Basic_models)
- Predator-prey : [Lotka-Voltera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations) and [Nicholson-Bayeux](http://www.inhs.uiuc.edu/research/biocontrol/theoriesmodels/nbmodel.html) models
- [Several species in competition for a resource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations)

Do you know any other mathematical models ? My aim is to simulate the dynamics of a human population and the aforementioned models are too simplistic for that, due to the lack of parameters.

Informatics models based on a system of rules like a cellular automata may be used for a more complex simulation. However, I would like to know if there is any mathematical equations for the dynamics of human population. I understand it is a difficult problem but surely much work must have been done on that.

Comment: "Mathematical demography" may be a useful keyword.

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed useful.

Comment: Mathematical ecology by Pielou is a great book with a lot of information about this.

Answer (score 2):

There are "age-specific population models." In these, you divide the population into groups by age, then assume that with the passage of time each individual in a given age group has a certain probability of survivng into the next age group, and that the females in a given age group have, on average, such and so many babies. You may find something about them by searching for that term, or by searching for "the Leslie matrix".